# If $V$ is a f.d. vector space, why is every right ideal of $\mathrm{End}_F(V)$ of form $I=\{T:\mathrm{im}(T)\subseteq W\}$ for $W$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

This is a qual problem from Spring 2011 at my university.

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space. Then every right ideal of $\mathrm{End}_F(V)$ is of form $I=\{T:\mathrm{im}(T)\subseteq W\}$ for some fixed subspace $W$.

A solution is found [here](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tdokos/alg_qual_pdfs/11spring.pdf), in problem 8, but I'm just curious if there are perhaps alternative, more elegant solutions. The proof there itself admits in an ending remark that it is a naive approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it as follows.

**1.** First note that *if $A,B\in {\rm End}(V)$ satisfy ${\rm im}(A)\subset {\rm im}(B)$, then one can find $C\in{\rm End}(V)$ such that $A=BC$*. This is the key point, and a well-known "exercise".

**1'.** If $S\in\mathcal I$, then any $T\in{\rm End}(V)$ such that ${\rm im}(T)\subset {\rm im}(S)$ belongs to $\mathcal I$. This follows immediately from **1**.

**2.** If $T_1,T_2\in\mathcal I$, then one can find $T\in\mathcal I$ such that ${\rm im}(T)$ contains ${\rm im}(T_1)$ and ${\rm im}(T_2)$. To see this write ${\rm im}(T_1)+{\rm im}(T_2)=V_1\oplus V_2\oplus V_3$, where $V_i\subset {\rm im}(T_i)$ for $i=1,2$ and $V_3={\rm im}(T_1)\cap {\rm im}(T_2)$. Then choose $E$ such that $V=E\oplus V_1\oplus V_2\oplus V_3$. For $i=1,2,3$, the associated projection $p_i$ onto $V_i$ belongs to $\mathcal I$ by **1'**. So $T=p_1+p_2+p_3\in \mathcal I$, and ${\rm im}(T)= {\rm im}(T_1)+{\rm im}(T_2)$.

**3.** It follows immediately from **2** that there exists $S\in\mathcal I$ such that ${\rm im}(T)\subset {\rm im}(S)$ for every $T\in\mathcal I$. Just take $S\in\mathcal I$ such that ${\rm im}(S)$ has maximal dimension. Setting $W:={\rm im}(S)$, it follows from **1'** that $\mathcal I=\{ T\in{\rm End}(V);\; {\rm im}(T)\subset W\}$.